# How can I initialize a Docker container with the result of running a shell script?

Tags: docker, tomcat, containers, dockerfile

I'm working on deploying a Tomcat application onto Docker and it's currently working, but only if I initialize some configurations and run it manually after starting the container.

A simplified version of my Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM tomcat:9.0.10-jre8
COPY setEnv.sh /usr/local/tomcat/bin
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/tomcat/bin/setEnv.sh

ADD application.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
RUN /usr/local/tomcat/bin/setEnv.sh # set $JAVA_OPTS
CMD /usr/local/tomcat/bin/startup.sh # start Tomcat application
```

I start the container with

```
docker run -ti -p 8080:8080 --rm --name app app-image
```

But when I start the container, nothing happens and the container just quits. I've tried using the -d tag instead but it hasn't helped.

The only way I can get it to work is if I instead run:

```
docker run -ti -p 8080:8080 --rm --name app app-image bash
```

When the shell script opens, $JAVA_OPTS is empty, so I have to run setEnv.sh manually, and then after running startup.sh manually my application successfully deploys onto Docker.

Obviously this isn't ideal though, because I don't want to have to manually run setEnv.sh every time. But if I'm able to run setEnv.sh through the Dockerfile so that $JAVA_OPTS is set at run-time, that should fix my issue.

What do I need to change here to make this work? Is it an issue with my Dockerfile or the way I'm running my container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is not working (but does work when you run the steps you described in bash) is because each step of a Dockerfile runs an isolated process - the environment is not shared between steps.

If you need to set environment variable in a Dockerfile the normal way to do so [would be using the `ENV` directive](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env). With this you can do something like this to set an environment variable:

```
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-..."
```

You can also set many at the same time with:

```
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-..." OTHER_VAR="..."
```

If your script has to do some processing to work out what the correct environment variables to set are then I think your best bet would be to change the `startup.sh` script to either call or source the other script to get the correct value. If you cannot change `startup.sh` then you could create a wrapper script which sets the env vars before calling `startup.sh`.

EDIT: For implementing the wrapper script I would do something like this:

```
#! /bin/sh

set -e

/usr/local/tomcat/bin/setEnv.sh         # Call this however you did in your bash session where it worked
/usr/local/tomcat/bin/startup.sh "$@"
```

This calls the `setEnv.sh` to set the environment variables and then the `startup.sh` (passing on any arguments which may have been passed).

Comment: Yup, I do need to use a separate setEnv.sh script, but writing a wrapper script for the two is a good idea. Still, how do I implement that in the Dockerfile or docker run command? Doesn't the same issue of the environment not being shared between steps still apply? Ideally I'd like to just start up the container and have the wrapper script immediately called, initializing $JAVA_OPTS and running the startup script.

Answer (score 1):

If the options are more dynamic, this is a typical use for an entrypoint script.  You can write a script that runs as the container is starting up, and it's given the `CMD` from the Dockerfile or whatever was passed at the end of the `docker run` command as arguments.  In this case it would be very simple:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Load in the environment variables
# ("." is the same as "source", but works in all POSIX shells)
. /usr/local/tomcat/bin/setEnv.sh

# Run the CMD (keeping it as pid 1)
exec "$@"
```

Then you can include this in your Dockerfile:

```
FROM tomcat:9.0.10-jre8
COPY setEnv.sh entrypoint.sh /usr/local/tomcat/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/tomcat/bin/entrypoint.sh
COPY application.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/tomcat/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/usr/local/tomcat/bin/startup.sh"]
```

The other important thing about this approach is that if you think something might be wrong in your image you can get a shell in a new container in the usual way

```
docker run --rm -it myimage sh
```

without trying to remember the syntax for `--entrypoint`, and still getting your first-time setup.  (It will run the entrypoint script, which will set environment variables and then `exec sh`.)